# Get average sales amount for the sales persons whose birth date comes in the current month

Tags: mysql

**Here is the query I have try:-**

```
select firstname,
       salesamt,
       avg(salesamt) 
from salesperson sp, salesfact s 
where sp.salespersonkey=s.salespersonkey and month(birthdate)=month(now()) 
group by firstname;
```

Here is the table records:
[image]

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

if you need  avg for fistname  then you  shoud not add  saleamnt in select clause

```
select firstname
,avg(salesamt) 
from salesperson sp
INNER JOIN  salesfact s ON sp.salespersonkey=s.salespersonkey 
      and month(birthdate)=month(now()) 
group by firstname;
```

if you use the same column in aggregation function and in group by you can't obtain  the aggregated  result

And you should not use the older implicit join sintax based  on where clause  you should use the more recent explicit join sintax based on INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

You can try with inner join but from your table it seems you'll not get any records
as one user only have birthday in current month and he has no records in salesfacta table

```
select firstname,avg(salesamt) from salesperson sp inner join 
salesfact s on sp.salespersonkey=s.salespersonkey
where month(birthdate)=month(now()) 
group by firstname
```